# Calcular un slice a partir de un índice imaginario dado en array con 3 Dimensiones

Tags: python, array, numpy, eficiencia, ciencia-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente problema:

•   Tengo un array de 3 dimensiones 9x9x9 lleno con números del 0 al 728

•   Debo imaginarme que se divide en 27 arrays de 3x3x3 tal como esta en la imagen

•   Debo crear una función, que pasándole como parámetro el numero del bloque (el numero grande),  me devuelva el slice para obtener ese bloque.

[image: Cubo en representación del array]

Por ejemplo, para el bloque 0, para obtener los valores de ese bloque se debe hacer el slice así:

```
a = np.arange(729).reshape(9,9,9) 
print(a)
print(a[0:3 , 0:3 , 0:3])
```

y se obtiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero entonces la idea es crear la función, que según, pasándole el índice (el numero grande), se devuelva el array que pertenezca a ese índice. Pensé hacerlo con un elseif y poner el slice correspondiente para cada caso pero lo veo muy ineficiente, no se si habrá otra mejor forma de hacerlo.

**Edit:** Aquí agrego lo que hice, pero queda muy largo :s
la idea es depronto hacer mas eficiente esa funcion slice block

```
import numpy as np

def sliceBlock(bloque):
    subArray= ""
    if(bloque == 0):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 0:3 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==1):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 0:3 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==2):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 0:3 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==3):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 3:6 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==4):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 3:6 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==5):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 3:6 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==6):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 6:9 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==7):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 6:9 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==8):
        subArray = a[0:3 , 6:9 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==9):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 0:3 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==10):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 0:3 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==11):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 0:3 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==12):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 3:6 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==13):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 3:6 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==14):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 3:6 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==15):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 6:9 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==16):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 6:9 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==17):
        subArray = a[3:6 , 6:9 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==18):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 0:3 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==19):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 0:3 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==20):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 0:3 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==21):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 3:6 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==22):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 3:6 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==23):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 3:6 , 6:9]
    elif(bloque ==24):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 6:9 , 0:3]
    elif(bloque ==25):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 6:9 , 3:6]
    elif(bloque ==26):
        subArray = a[6:9 , 6:9 , 6:9]
    else:
        subArray = "Ese bloque no existe"        
    return subArray

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.arange(729).reshape(9,9,9)
    print("Array Completo:")
    print(a)
    while(True):
        print("Digite -1 si quiere salir")
        block = int(input("Digite el indice del cubo: "))
        print("-------------------------------")
        if(block == -1):
            break
        else:
            print(sliceBlock(block),"\n")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Baldomer Perez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Agrega por favor lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora nos ayudará a ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se pueden computar los índices del slice con una fórmula.

La rodaja general que queremos obtener es:

```
a[i0:i0+3 , i1:i1+3 , i2:i2+3]
```

Solo nos queda encontrar qué fórmula nos daría el valor adecuado para `i0`, `i1` e `i2` en función del número de bloque.

Tratando de razonarlo, pero también mediante un poco de ensayo y error, he encontrado que la fórmula sería la siguiente:

- Si dividimos el número de bloque entre 9, nos sale 0 para los primeros 9 números de bloque, 1 para los 9 siguientes y 2 para los 9 útimos. Multiplicando ese valor por 3 sale `i0`.
- Si dividimos el número de bloque entre 3 salen números 0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3, 4,4,4 etc.. según va creciendo el número de bloque. Tomando el módulo 3 de esos números sale ya un ciclo: 0,0,0, 1,1,1, 2,2,2, 0,0,0, 1,1,1, ... Multiplicando eso por 3 tenemos el índice `i1`
- Si hacemos el módulo 3 del número de bloque sale el ciclo 0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2, ... para números de bloque crecientes. Basta multiplicar por 3 esos y ya tenemos `i2`.

Así pues, una función que nos computaría los índices apropiados para los slices, en función del número de bloque, sería la siguiente:

```py
def calcular_indices(n):
  i0, i1, i2 = n//9*3, (n//3)%3*3, n%3*3 
  return tuple(slice(i, i+3) for i in (i0, i1, i2))
```

Un ejemplo, si le pasamos como número de bloque `n` el 2 por ejemplo, obtenemos:

```
>>> calcular_indices(2)
(slice(0, 3, None), slice(0, 3, None), slice(6, 9, None))
```

Lo que quiere decir que hay que usar `a[0:3, 0:3, 6:9]` para obtener el bloque 1.

Ya podemos entonces escribir la función buscada:

```
def sliceBlock(a, bloque):
  x, y, z = calcular_indices(bloque)
  return a[x, y, z]
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
>>> print(sliceBlock(a, 1))
[[[  3   4   5]
  [ 12  13  14]
  [ 21  22  23]]

 [[ 84  85  86]
  [ 93  94  95]
  [102 103 104]]

 [[165 166 167]
  [174 175 176]
  [183 184 185]]]
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ese análisis estuvo muy bueno, en el código que yo había realizado si había notado un patrón bastante sospechoso en los slices pero no se me había ocurrido como sacarle provecho.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma un poco más performante es reemplazar los bloques `if` por un diccionario con las soluciones precalculadas:

```
def sliceBlock(a, bloque):

    soluciones = {
        0: a[0:3 , 0:3 , 0:3],
        1: a[0:3 , 0:3 , 3:6],
        2: a[0:3 , 0:3 , 6:9],
        3: a[0:3 , 3:6 , 0:3],
        4: a[0:3 , 3:6 , 3:6],
        5: a[0:3 , 3:6 , 6:9],
        6: a[0:3 , 6:9 , 0:3],
        7: a[0:3 , 6:9 , 3:6],
        8: a[0:3 , 6:9 , 6:9],
        9: a[3:6 , 0:3 , 0:3],
        10: a[3:6 , 0:3 , 3:6],
        11: a[3:6 , 0:3 , 6:9],
        12: a[3:6 , 3:6 , 0:3],
        13: a[3:6 , 3:6 , 3:6],
        14: a[3:6 , 3:6 , 6:9],
        15: a[3:6 , 6:9 , 0:3],
        16: a[3:6 , 6:9 , 3:6],
        17: a[3:6 , 6:9 , 6:9],
        18: a[6:9 , 0:3 , 0:3],
        19: a[6:9 , 0:3 , 3:6],
        20: a[6:9 , 0:3 , 6:9],
        21: a[6:9 , 3:6 , 0:3],
        22: a[6:9 , 3:6 , 3:6],
        23: a[6:9 , 3:6 , 6:9],
        24: a[6:9 , 6:9 , 0:3],
        25: a[6:9 , 6:9 , 3:6],
        26: a[6:9 , 6:9 , 6:9]
    }
    return soluciones.get(bloque, None)

print(sliceBlock(a, 1))
[[[  3   4   5]
  [ 12  13  14]
  [ 21  22  23]]

 [[ 84  85  86]
  [ 93  94  95]
  [102 103 104]]

 [[165 166 167]
  [174 175 176]
  [183 184 185]]]
```

La única critica que tengo para esta solución es que no es generalizable a arrays de múltiples dimensiones.

Comment: El uso del diccionarios ahí estuvo interesante, no se me hubiera ocurrido hacerlo así, pero es verdad, para arrays de múltiples dimensiones queda corto, aunque me gusto bastante la solución de **abulafia**, queda bastante pequeño el código calculando los índices de esa forma.